# STI + multiple FK on one column

Tags: foreign-keys, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

There are tables:

```
comments(id, body, object_kind(photo, topic, ...), object_id),
photos(id, title),
topics(id, title, body),
...(id, ...).
```

How it possible link using FK object_kind+object_id with suitable row in related tables? And create `onCascade=DELETE` (remove comments of topic when removing topic).

One of sollution: create separate columns to each relation type: `comment_id`, `photo_id`, but I'm trying find more flexible sollution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. Only separate columns like `comment_id`, `photo_id` which are `nullable=true`